Joining the $2^k$ points of $\{0,1\}^k$ with the shortest tree
Let $k$ be a given positive integer, and then consider the unit hypercube $\{0, 1\}^k \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ (i.e., a $k$-dimensional "cube" in the well-known Euclidean space).
We need to join all the $2^k$ vertices of the stated hypercube by using a Euclidean Steiner tree, which is a spanning tree of the original vertices plus zero or more new vertices (Steiner points) such that we minimise the total Euclidean length of the edges in the tree. Denote the total length of these optimal trees as $l_{min}(k)$, for any integer $k$ (e.g., $l_{min}(1) = 1$, $l_{min}(2) = 1 + \sqrt{3}$, $l_{min}(3) \approx 6.196$, and so forth).
I wonder if solving the problem for every $k$ would be doable. I can only point out that an upper bound is trivially given by $2^k-1$ and that the trick to join $2^{k-1}$ pairs of opposite vertices does not improve the mentioned trivial solution as $k$ goes above $3$.
The figure below constructively shows that $l_{min}(3) \leq 4 \cdot \sqrt{2} + 1$.

P.S.
For any $k + 1$ we can also recycle our best tree, double it and then spend a unit segment to join the two subtrees, so $l_{min}(k+1) \le 1 + 2 l_{min}(k)$.
P.P.S.
The user Noam D. Elkies suggested in a comment of the present thread that $l_{min}(k) < l_{upper}(k)$ holds for every $k>2$ (since my value of $l_{upper}(2)$ is certainly bigger than the optimal solution of the square Steiner tree problem and thus $l_{min}(3) < 4 \cdot \sqrt{2} + 1$ follows). Noam was definitely right since in this paper the solution $l_{upper}(2) = 1 + \sqrt{3}$ is given (see Figure 2 from the Reference above).

The picture above is not a tree, but a forest, since it isn't connected.

It seems $l_{min}(3)<4\sqrt{2}+1$. E.g. consider a tree formed by joining the vertices of ${0,1}^3$ with $x_3=1$ to $(0.5,0.5,0.9)$, the ones with $x_3=0$ to $(0.5,0.5,0.1)$ and add the segment from $(0.5,0.5,0.1)$ to $(0.5,0.5,0.9)$

Also see this question for the case $k=2$ (seems like this is called the Steiner tree problem)

@GerryMyerson :  My understanding is that the OP defines a tree to be a collection of line segments that is connected as a topological space, regardless of whether it is connected as a graph (and also presumably regardless of whether it is simply connected).

For starters you can improve on that tree by replacing each X by a Steiner tree for the four vertices of a square.

@Steven, you may be right, in which case I'd say OP has no business making up new meanings for standard terms.

For $k=3$, the optimum value is apparently approximately 6.196, per Bridges, Minimal Steiner Trees for Three Dimensional Networks, Mathematical Gazette Vol. 78, No. 482 (Jul., 1994), pp. 157-162. I don't have access to the paper itself and am relying on other sources which reference it.

@NoamD.Elkies I originally considered the tree ${{(0,0,0)-(1,1,0)}\cup{(1,0,0)-(0,1,0)}\cup{(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0)-(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1)}\cup{(0,0,1)-(1,1,1)}\cup{(1,0,1)-(0,1,1)}$ with the two Steiner points  $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}, 0)$ and $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1)$, but I finally changed the picture as the above.
Anyway, we agree that $2^k-1$ cannot be a solution for $k=3$ even by considering the tree whose branches meet in $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ and that joins every vertex of the unit cube from the center.

@MarcoRipà can you please fix  the picture in your question; it is no connected spanning tree and can you also clearly define whether the tree edges connect corners of the hypercube or if there may also be other vertices?

@ManfredWeis The problem is not the picture, but the misleading terminology. The vertices of the trees are not supposed to be the vertices of the hypercube; you can add new vertices. So the question is not about spanning trees in the hypercube graph.

@EmilJeřábek Picture edited. Please, let me know if the problem is clearly stated or if you wish the first lines of the post to meet a different definition with regards to the one considered in this article (that I also cited in previous papers of mine): https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Covering-Grids-by-Trees-Dumitrescu-T%C3%B3th/62989bdc3351ef8a8146b4e26b6c20b920a98ab2

The problem is that, both in the title and in the text, when you write “join the vertices of the hypercube using a tree”, it strongly suggests that the vertices of the tree are vertices of the hypercube; moreover, this is the most natural thing that anyone familiar with graph theory would expect you to do. So unless one reads very carefully the rest of the text, it is prone to misunderstanding.

I believe that whenever $n$ edges meet in one vertex in the optimal solution, they have to meet like the edges to the center of a regular tetrahedron. For example when 3 edges meet they should all have 120° angles between them.

@HenrikRüping, what little I can read of the paper I linked above (the first page) seems to suggest that this is incorrect in 3D (and presumably higher dimensions).

Thanks. It actually gives a better condition, namely that all the unit vectors pointing outwards need to add up to zero. This seems to show that the picture above is not optimal and by moving $S_1$ and $S_2$ inward a little bit, we should get a smaller total length.

What does “$l_{upper}$” refer to in the P.P.S.? It’s not defined in the question.

@HenrikRüping Mathematica thinks that you can get a total length of $\sqrt{30}+1 \approx 6.477$ at best if you keep $S_1$ and $S_2$ on the central axis. It's not reaching the bound $6.196$ mentioned by OP though.

I skimmed through the Bridges paper. It’s not clear to me whether he really claims the value $1+3\sqrt3\approx6{.}196$ for $k=3$ is optimal, or whether it’s just the best he could find. FWIW, this is what it looks like: https://i.sstatic.net/Lhaeb69d.png

An optimum Steiner tree always has all internal vertices $3$-valent and all angles equal to $120^{\circ}$ (even in higher dimensions).

My guess is that the optimum is given by the tree with $2^k+2^{k-1} + \cdots + 2 = 2^{k+1}-2$ vertices, labeled by strings of the form $x_1 x_2 \cdots x_j$ with $x_i \in { \pm 1 }$ and $1 \leq j \leq k$. Here $(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$ is the corresponding vertex of the cube, there are edges from $(x_1, \ldots, x_j)$ to $(x_1, \ldots, x_j, 1)$ and $(x_1, \ldots, x_j, -1)$, as well as a central edge from $(1)$ to $(-1)$, and all the angles are $120^{\circ}$. I don't know how to efficiently compute the coordinates of these vertices.

@EmilJeřábek I implicitly assumed that taking $l_{upper}(k)$ as a proven upper bound for the given $k$-dimensional case of our problem would be clear by context. Basically, we have that $l_{upper}(k) \geq l_{min}(k)$ should hold for any $k$ and it must describe the total length of the tree that has been proven to be a valid tree for the given problem.

About the mentioned Bridges' paper, I wonder whether or not we have the exact formula for that sub $6.2$ value (I cannot read the full text right now).

@DavidESpeyer, by analogy with the extension from 2D to 3D it seems that you might be able to lift dimensions easily enough. If $P_{k,i}$ are the vertices of the solution in $k$ dimensions, translate to coordinate $\tfrac 12$ in the $(k+1)$th dimension and turn each edge to a leaf $(\vec{v}, \tfrac 12)$ into a fork which covers $(\vec{v}, \tfrac 12 \pm \tfrac 12)$ by finding the isogonal point.

I figured out how to get $1+3 \sqrt{3}$. (Except that I used a cube of side length $2$, so I got $2+6 \sqrt{3}$). Let $r_1 = 1-1/\sqrt{3}$, $r_2 = 1/\sqrt{3}$, $r_3 = 2 /\sqrt{3}$; let $u_1 = (1,0,0)$, $u_2 = (1/2, \sqrt{3}/2,0)$, $u_3 = (1/4, \sqrt{3}/2, \sqrt{3}/2)$. Then three of the vertices are at $r_1 u_1=(1-1/\sqrt{3},0,0)$, $r_1 u_1 + r_2 u_2=(1-1/(2\sqrt{3}),1/2,0)$ and $r_1 u_1 + r_2 u_2 +r_3 u_3 = (1,1,1)$, and the other vertices are gotten by changing the signs of coordinates. The total length is $2 r1 + 4 r2 + 8 r3 = 2+6\sqrt{3}$.

Using the recursive construction of my previous comment it appears that $l_{min}(k) \le 1 + (2^{k-1}-1)\sqrt 3$.

@PeterTaylor You are onto something. It does seem that we can build the $k$-dimensional solution from the $k-1$ dimensional solution by (1) embedding the $k-1$ dimensional solution in the plane $z_k=0$, through the center of the cube and (2) for each edge from an internal vertex $v$ to a leaf $x$, introducing a new vertex at the isogonal point of $(v,0)$, $(x,-1)$ and $(x,1)$ and joining it in the obvious way. It wasn't clear to me that this should happen until I solved the linear equations in my answer; do you have a more direct intuition?

@DavidESpeyer, I managed to reproduce Bridges' value for 3D about the same time that Emil posted it above, and I noticed visually that the 2D projection matches the 2D solution. Obviously since the three edges around a Steiner point are coplanar, if you look parallel to the plane they project to a line. That's about as much intuition as I had: the rest was calculation up to 6D to sanity-check that it gave something reasonable.

I suspect that the optimum, for a cube of side length $2$, is $2^k \sqrt{3} - 2 \sqrt{3}+2$. Note that the optimum if we use edges of the cube is $2 (2^k-1)$, so this is better by a factor of roughly $\sqrt{3}/2$. (Side comment: For trees in the plane, there is a famous conjecture of Gilbert and Pollack (1968) that adding extra vertices can never decrease the length by a factor better than $\sqrt{3}/2\approx 0.866$. However, in $k$-dimensional space, better improvements are possible; Gilbert and Chung (1976) give examples with ratio approaching $\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4-\sqrt{2}} \approx 0.669$. It is peculiar that this particular $k$-dimensional problem seems to have the same ratio as the conjectured worst case of the $2$-dimensional problem.)
The form of the solution: I'll write $\vec{e}_1$,..., $\vec{e}_k$ for the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^k$. The vertices of my cube are at $x_1 \vec{e}_1 + \cdots + x_k \vec{e}_k$ for $x_1$, ..., $x_k \in \{ \pm 1 \}$.
I will add an extra $2$-valent vertex denoted $v( )$ at the center $(0,0,\ldots, 0)$ of the cube. It will be at the midpoint of an edge, so we can erase it at the end, but it makes the notation more symmetric.
Combinatorially, my tree is the perfect binary rooted tree with $1+2+\cdots + 2^{k-1}+2^k$ vertices. A general vertex will be denoted $v(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_j)$ where $0 \leq j \leq k$ and each $x_i$ is $\pm 1$. The root is $v()$ at position $(0,0,\ldots,0)$; the $2^k$ leaves are the vertices of the cube, with $v(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k)$ at $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k) = x_1 \vec{e}_1 + \cdots + x_k \vec{e}_k$. In general, the children of $v(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_j)$ are $v(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_j, 1)$ and $v(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_j, (-1))$.
I'll abbreviate $v(\overbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}^j)$ to $v(1^j)$. If I figure out the coordiantes of the $v(1^j)$, then the other vertices at level $j$ are obtained by switching the sign of the coordinates in all possible ways. Let $\vec{u}_j$ be the unit vector in direction $v(1^j) - v(1^{j-1})$ and let $r_j$ be the length of the edge $(v(1^{j-1}), v(1^j))$. So $v(1^j)$ is in position $r_1 \vec{u}_1 + \cdots + r_j \vec{u}_j$. The rest of this post is computing the values of the $\vec{u}_j$ and $r_j$.
Computing the $\vec{u}_j$ Look at the vertex $v(1^j)$ for $1 \leq j \leq k$. Its neighbors are $v(1^{j-1})$, $v(1^{j+1})$ and $v(1^j (-1))$. These four vertices lie in an affine two-plane $P$. By symmetry, the vertices $v(1^{j-1})$ and $v(1^j)$ are on $\vec{e}_{j+1}^{\perp}$ and $v(1^{j+1})$ and $v(1^j(-1))$  are reflections of each other over $e_{j+1}^{\perp}$. Thus, $(\vec{u}_j, \vec{e}_{j+1})$ is an orthonormal basis for $P$. We want $\vec{u}_{j+1}$ and $-\vec{u}_j$ to make a $120^{\circ}$ angle, so we should have
$$\vec{u}_{j+1} = (\cos 60^{\circ}) \vec{u}_j + (\sin 60^{\circ}) \vec{e}_{j+1} = \frac{1}{2} \vec{u}_j +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \vec{e}_{j+1}  \tag{1}$$
Using $(1)$ recursively with the base case $\vec{u}_1 = \vec{e}_1$, we get
$$\vec{u}_j = \frac{1}{2^{j-1}} \vec{e}_1 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2^{j-1}} \vec{e}_2 + \cdots + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \vec{e}_{j-1} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \vec{e}_j. \tag{2}$$
Computing the $r_j$: We want to have
$$r_1 \vec{u}_1 + \cdots + r_k \vec{u}_k = (1,1,\ldots,1) \tag{3}.$$
Extracting the $j$-th component of $(3)$, and using $(2)$, we get
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
r_1+\frac{1}{2} r_2 + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{k-1}} r_k &=& 1 & \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} r_j + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} r_{j+1} + \cdots + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2^{k-j+1}} r_k &=& 1 & \text{for}\ j \geq 2 \\
\end{array} \tag{4}$$
Solving $(4)$ recursively (starting at $r_k$ and working back to $r_1$), I get
$$r_j = \begin{cases} 1-1/\sqrt{3} & j=1 \\ 1/\sqrt{3} & 2 \leq j \leq k-1 \\ 2/\sqrt{3} & j=k. \end{cases} \tag{5}.$$
The total length of the tree is
$$
\begin{align}
2 r_1 + 4 r_2 + \cdots + 2^k r_k &= 2(1-1/\sqrt{3}) + (4+8+\cdots+2^{k-1})/\sqrt{3} + 2^k \cdot 2/\sqrt{3} \\ &= 2^k \sqrt{3} - 2 \sqrt{3}+2.
\end{align}$$
In case this formula is useful to anyone, for $1 \leq j \leq k-1$, we have
$$v(1^j) = {\Big(}1-\frac{1}{2^{j-1} \sqrt{3}},\ 1-\frac{1}{2^{j-1}}, 1-\frac{1}{2^{j-2}},\ \ldots,\ 1-\frac{1}{4},\ 1-\frac{1}{2},\ 0,0,\ldots,0 {\Big)}.$$

As mentioned above, an optimal Steiner tree always has all interior vertices trivalent and all angles equal to $120^{\circ}$. See, for example, the first paragraph of Section 6.1 in
Hwang, Frank K.; Richards, Dana S.; Winter, Pawel, The Steiner tree problem, Annals of Discrete Mathematics. 53. Amsterdam: North-Holland. xi, 339 p. (1992). ZBL0774.05001.
So the remaining problem is to guess which trivalent tree with $2^k$ labeled leaves to use. This one seems like the best choice, but I have no idea how to prove that it can't be improved on.

There are obviously equivalent trees by permuting the basis, but in higher dimensions it's also possible to rotate subtrees, so a proof of optimality has to take that into account. My intuition is that it would begin by considering how the vertices can be paired up and which plane the edges of a given pair must lie in.
